# When do we use Synchronised on a java method that handles 'GET'?

Tags: java, multithreading, web, concurrency, thread-safety

Trying to understand Concurrency Concepts.
 I saw a springboot application with a Controller Class that had 2 methods:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/r1", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<> function1(...){...}
```

and another one in the same class as:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/r2", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public synchronized ResponseEntity<>(...){....}
```

My question is if both methods are in the same class and since a synchronised method locks the whole object of that class, doesn't it lock the non-synchronised method as well?

Comment: "doesn't it lock the non-synchronised method as well?" no. A synchronized (instance) method is simply a method where the body is wrapped in `synchronized (this) { /* body */ }`.

Comment: Synchronization does not 'lock' anything in the way you're suggesting.  It merely ensures that only one of the synchronized sequences executes at a time.  Code that does not synchronize is not affected.

Answer (score 1):

**Question :** My question is if both methods are in the same class and since a synchronised method locks the whole object of that class, doesn't it lock the non-synchronised method as well?

**Answer :** No, Only the synchronized methods will be blocked while all other threads are trying to call synchronized method on same object.

[Synchronized Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) From the documentation it is clear, at a time only one thread can execute the synchronized method on object, where all other thread that try executing synchronized method on same object will be blocked.

But still two threads can execute the synchronized method at a time, if they use two different objects

> First, it is not possible for two invocations of synchronized methods on the same object to interleave.**When one thread is executing a synchronized method for an object, all other threads that invoke synchronized methods for the same object block (suspend execution) until the first thread is done with the object.**
>
> Second, when a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a synchronized block, you have to give it an object to lock on, like this:

```
Object o = new Object();
synchronized (o) {
    // do something
}
```

If you want, you could use the object instance itself by using `this` instead of `o`, like this:

```
synchronized (this) {
    // do something
}
```

If you have two methods and you want one lock that protects both methods, you could do this:

```
Object o = new Object();
public void methodOne() {
    synchronized (o) {
        // do something
    }
}
public void methodTwo() {
    synchronized (o) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

And like before, you can use `this` instead of a separate object `o`, like this:

```
public void methodOne() {
    synchronized (this) {
        // do something
    }
}
public void methodTwo() {
    synchronized (this) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

or you can achieve the same thing by marking both of those methods as `sychronized`, becuase synchronized methods will lock on the object instance:

```
public synchronized void methodOne() {
    // do something
}
public synchronized void methodTwo() {
    // do something
}
```

Non-synchronized methods will not block on anything.